# How to use VBA variable in SQL string? Enter Parameter Value error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I get a popup box asking for the parameter value for the value of CXIid

> Enter Parameter Value
>    for CXI00012.

I tried `' " & CXIid & " '` but then I get a result of 0 rows being updated. However when I put a value in the where clause or into the Enter Parameter Value prompt I get the correct row updated.

How do I get it to recognize CXIid as a value?

```vb
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim CXIid As String
Dim testSQL As String

CXIid = Form_sf_ParticipantView.CXI_ID

testSQL = "UPDATE [tbl_Participants]" & _
            "SET tbl_Participants.Consent = (Forms.frmReturn.cboConsent.value)" & _
            "WHERE ((tbl_Participants.CXI_ID = " & CXIid & " ));"

DoCmd.RunSQL testSQL
```

Comment: is `CXI_ID` a number or a string.  If it is a string you should use the `'` but with out spaces between the `'` and the `"`: `'" & CXIid & "'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different types of mistakes... the variables cannot be within the quotes, and since the *field* `CXI_ID` is a `String`, it ***does*** need quotes.

This assumes that the `Consent` field is numeric and the combobox is returning a numeric value as well.

```
testSQL = "UPDATE [tbl_Participants]" & _
          " SET tbl_Participants.Consent = " & Forms.frmReturn.cboConsent.value & _
          " WHERE tbl_Participants.CXI_ID = '" & CXIid & "'"
```

<sub>Also note the spaces I added before SET and WHERE. Those are important.</sub>

Use `MsgBox testSQL` or `Debug.Print testSQL` to double check what `testSQL` is set to before you run it.

If the field `CXI_ID` is not a string but you are just using a string as the type of variable holding the value for some reason:

```
testSQL = "UPDATE [tbl_Participants]" & _
          " SET tbl_Participants.Consent = " & Forms.frmReturn.cboConsent.value & _
          " WHERE tbl_Participants.CXI_ID = " & CXIid
```

If they are both strings:

```
testSQL = "UPDATE [tbl_Participants]" & _
          " SET tbl_Participants.Consent = '" & Forms.frmReturn.cboConsent.value  & "'" & _
          " WHERE tbl_Participants.CXI_ID = '" & CXIid & "'"
```